# Extract text from HTML, exclude text in <small> tags

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want to extract text from HTML, without the `<small>` tag:

```
<h1>THE BIG TEXT<small>the small text</small></h1>
```

I can extract "THE BIG TEXT the small text" with `//h1/text()`, but how can I extract "THE BIG TEXT" only, without "the small text"?

What XPath do I have to use?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath should work:

```
//h1/text()
```

It will find the immediate text inside the `h1` tag not the child tag.
It extracts "THE BIG TEXT".

Demo [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/04bf4b501e387339ae90162ebe906707).

But if you want to extract all text inside `h1` **including** the child tags:

```
//h1//text()
```

It extracts "THE BIG TEXT the small text".

Look at the single and double slashes (`/`). Single `/` means immediate and double `/` means all including nested.